# Charge of the Light Bridage

Tags: possessives, poetry

> "Forward, the Light Brigade!"
>   Was there a man dismay'd?
>   Not tho' the soldier knew
>   Someone had blunder'd:
>   *Theirs* not to make reply,
>   *Theirs* not to reason why,
>   *Theirs* but to do and die:
>   Into the valley of Death
>   Rode the six hundred.

I was wondering about the use of "theirs" in this poem. For me it feels like "*there* is but to do and die" would make more sense. Obviously I am wrong somewhere. Can anyone tell why the poet uses *their*?

Comment: Thanks for reformatting your post; it's much easier to read now.

Answer (score 3):

"Theirs not to" here seems to mean "their job is not to", or "it does not fall to them to" or "it's not their responsibility to"

If we take the original:

> Theirs not to make reply, 
>   Theirs not to reason why, 
>  
>   Theirs but to do and die:

and rephrase it slightly:

> Their job is not to make reply, 
>   Their job is not to reason why, 
>  
>   Their job is to do and die:

Less poetic, but more clear. Looking at a [Sparknotes](https://www.sparknotes.com/poetry/tennyson/section9.rhtml) or [Schmoop](http://www.shmoop.com/charge-of-light-brigade-poem/stanza-2-summary.html) analysis supports this reading. In particular, Schmoop says:

> The speaker uses these lines to sum up all of the honest, humble heroism of these men. They're just doing their job. That job doesn't let permit them to talk back to their commanders ("make reply") or to figure out the point of the attack ("reason why"). All they can do is to ride and fight and possibly die ("do and die").